# cURL and submit button of JavaScript -> ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I am using **cURL** to try to login in this website https://myportal.vtc.edu.hk/wps/portal/ , but i found that there is a **javascript function**

```
<"onclick="GoLogin(); return false;">
```

to control the login access.

so i can't connect to this website, this is my code below,

```
<?php

$username = 'userid';
$password = 'password';
$loginUrl = 'https://myportal.vtc.edu.hk/wps/portal';`


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'userid='.$username.'&password='.$password );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myportal.vtc.edu.hk/wps/myportal/!ut/p/c4/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hTC39DAxNz98CwMEtTA08f50DjQEdzIwMDI_2CbEdFABEW-jM!/');

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

This is the GoLogin() function :

```
      $.ajax({
              url:      loginForm.attr('action'),

            cache:      false,

            async:      false,

            data:       params,

            type:       "POST",

            complete:   function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

                if (jqXHR.status == 200)  {

                    // login successfull
                    window.location = '/wps/myportal';

                } else if (jqXHR.status == 399) {

                    // login successfull

                    window.location = jqXHR.responseText;
                }
```

how can i login to this website, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This way you will not able to connect as via curl you can not execute the javascript.

For above requirement you should use the http://phantomjs.org/ .

Its php library is also available.

https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs

Or you can look at http://slimerjs.org/.

Comment: can you give some example, because i don't know how to use it.